# Error while trying to insert into database through form. SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

I have a small problem when trying to grab data from a form and add it to a table called objects inside a database called test.

When I open the form, add some info and press submit, I get this error:

> Fatal error: 
>    Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>    column 'Mr' in 'field list' in *path**

The HTML and PHP code are in two separate files under the same dir.

page_1.php

```
<form action="connect.php" method="post">
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br />
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br />
    About: <textarea name="about"></textarea><br />
    <input type="reset" name="reset">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

connect.php

```
try{
    $dh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test','root','');
    $dh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['about'];
$name = $_POST['fname'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO objects (post_title, post_content, post_name, post_date)
          VALUES ({$title}, {$content}, {$name})";
$query = $dh->query($sql);

while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $r->post_name, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: you just missed to add the date

Comment: Is `post_date` have any default constraint as `CURDATE()`? If so remove `post_date` from the `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 mistakes.

- number of columns does not match number of values (4 columns, 3 values)
- you are inserting unquoted *string* values - that doesn't work
- you're not using **prepared statements** but you're using `PDO`, so there should be no excuse there
- you're issuing an `INSERT` query and you're trying to treat it as if it were a `SELECT` query. That's not making sense at all.

Code that uses prepared statements, and produces working query that's safe against SQL injections would look like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO objects (post_title, post_content, post_name, post_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");

$stmt->execute(array($_POST['title'], $_POST['about'], $_POST['fname']));
```

If you require the inserted record, then issue another query that selects newly created record, also using prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO objects (post_title, post_content, post_name, post_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");

$stmt->execute(array($_POST['title'], $_POST['about'], $_POST['fname']));

$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = ?");

$stmt->execute(array($id));

// Now the record is in an array, no need to while loop over it.
$record = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you I got it working in the end. I use prepared statements, just removed them for the purpose of learning how "forms to database" works.